# Cannot get esp8266 - 12 wifi module to always read analogRead incoming voltage accurately

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, analogread, analogwrite

So I have and arduino uno that is firing an output on pin 8. This code is not in this file just to be clear. From there Im taking that output and using it to fire pin 0 on the wifi module. Im using pin 0 because from what I understand all other pins have a pullup or pulldown resistor. When pin 0 is hot I want to print that value. Sometimes it works when I do it other times the analog values reads very low. I am using the 3.3v from the arduino uno and I plan to get a voltage regulator for the wifi module but would this cause this kind of issue? I am very very new to arduino so if anyone has any ideas I would appreciate a very dumbed down explanation. Thanks a lot. Also the reason why I have the delay turned down so low is because it seemed to make the analog signal pick up more often. Im not sure why this would matter but at a delay of 3000 it would almost never change analog value but when I turned the delay down to one the value came through much more consistently. Currently the code just outputs low analog numbers and occasionally pops up 1023 when voltage is applied but not consistently. And sometimes it just stops altogether until I keep trying for a while. I am getting voltage to the pin however so I know I have a complete circuit and power.

## include

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "ENDOWED Underwear";
const char* password = "endowwear";

HTTPClient http;

static const uint8_t D0   = 16;
static const uint8_t D1   = 5;
static const uint8_t D2   = 4;
static const uint8_t D3   = 0;
static const uint8_t D4   = 2;
static const uint8_t D5   = 14;
static const uint8_t D6   = 12;
static const uint8_t D7   = 13;
static const uint8_t D8   = 15;
static const uint8_t D9   = 3;
static const uint8_t D10  = 1;

int featherPin = D3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(featherPin, INPUT);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(10);
    Serial.println("Waiting for connection");
  }
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(featherPin);

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.println("yay connect");

        http.begin("http://10.150.40.121:3000/");
        http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");

        int httpCode = http.POST("Message from ESP8266");
        String payload = http.getString();
//        Serial.println(payload);
        http.end();

    } else {
        Serial.println("Error in Wifi connection"); 
    }

    if (sensorValue > 850) {

      http.begin("http://10.150.40.121:3000/home");
      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");

      int httpCode = http.POST("Message from ESP8266");
      String payload = http.getString();
      Serial.println(payload);
      Serial.print("hi");
      http.end();
      } else if (sensorValue < 850) {
        Serial.print(sensorValue);
//        Serial.println("I am not hot");
      } 


//  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
//  delayMicroseconds(1);
//  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
//  delayMicroseconds(2);
//  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
//
//  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
//  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
//
//  inches = (duration / 2) / 74;
//  Serial.println(inches);
//
//  spaceIntruded = inches;
//  
//  if (spaceIntruded <= 50 || spaceIntruded >= 900){
//      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
//      digitalWrite(hornPin, HIGH); 
//      Serial.println("Intruder Detected!");
//      Serial.println("Sending text Notification...");
//      delay(500);
//      Serial.println("Armed...");
//  }
//  
//  else{
//    digitalWrite(hornPin, LOW);
//    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
//  }
    delay(1);

}
```

Comment: `When pin 0 is hot I want to print that value`...? What value? What do you mean by "hot"?

Comment: When pin 0 on the Arduino uno is hot meaning it has 3.3v applied to it I want to analogRead the change in value. If no voltage is applied it should read as a lot number and when voltage is applied it should read as a high number and sometimes it does but it in no way consistent. Im not sure if its because Im taking the 3.3v from the arduino uno but i also tried taking it from the 5v on the arduino uno and steeping it down with a voltage regulator and Im getting the same issue. However it was adjustable voltage regulator. Im going to get one that is specifically for 3.3v.

Comment: Do you have the pin connected to the analog input pin as well as pin 0?  You do know that the ESP8266 has only one analog input, and that is a special pin and not one of the normal Dx pins, yes?

Comment: No I didnt and I not to clear on what you mean by DX pin and I have pins soldered for each pin and im am maunally touching the output from the arduino uno to the 0 pin and no consistent change occurs. As of right now its working at all but at times it does. But the pin is not connected to an analog pin its just a pin. All the pins are soldered on and im only using pin 0 cause it doesnt have a pullup pulldown internal resistor. When tried using the other pins I couldnt get the value to change at all. Only when I chnaged to 0 did it read the change sometimes.

Comment: https://www.microcenter.com/product/460313/feather-huzzah-with-esp8266-wifi
This is the wifi module I am using

Comment: The pin labelled ADC is the only one that can be used with analogRead. And unless that board includes a divider it can't read more than 1V.

Comment: Do you think I could step down the voltage to one volt and work with it that way. I'm only keeping track of one value or how would ypu go about it. I have two files one for arduino uno and one for the feather. I just want to read and chnage the state of one pin. I set of a sensor in the arduino program that fires an input and makes kne pin on the Wi-Fi module that I can read the change from low to high. I also dont know much about rx TX but ive read I can talk to the module or should I use a different Wi-Fi module. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes. Yes you can. Google knows how.

Comment: I understand Google knows how. Ive googled my way up to this point. I'm just seeking some direction from someone with experience becuase I just started learning two days ago so certain things I'm confused on. Ive read dozens of articles so if you could guide me in a direction or maybe explain it from your point of virw I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The key word, which I have already mentioned, is "divider". Specifically voltage divider. A basic principle of electronics that you need to learn. The board may already have it though, so check the manual or schematic.

Comment: This is cool. Thank you. I need this. My last question is the pin labeled adc can I treat this pin like a regular analog read as far as the code goes and do you know why I cant do a digital read. Is it because its floating until its not. I'm mainly curious now. Thanks again. This is helpful.

Comment: why do you want to use troubled ADC of the esp8266 if you have an Uno with 5 good analog inputs in project setup?

Comment: The ADC pin can *only* be used with `analogRead()`. No other pin can, and nothing else can be done with the ADC pin. It is directly connected to the ADC internal to the chip and nothing else. You can't use `digitalRead()`, `digitalWrite()`, `pinMode()` or `analogWrite()`. It doesn't even have a pin number to use with those functions.

Comment: Majenko is right that the only pin you can use with **analogRead** is pin A0. I would add that I think you are making a mistake in assuming that any of those other pins can be used. I'm also new to this but I have two NodeMCU ESP8266 units and only a few pins are actually useful as input or output. Many of the pins are dedicated to other uses like serial RX/TX, storage, and RST. Pin D3, in particular, is reserved for FLASH. Some info [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-pinout-reference-gpios/).

Comment: I would also add that **analogWrite** does NOT just set some voltage level on a pin. The pins can only go to 0 or 3.3 -- i.e., completely **on** or completely **off**. In order to *emulate* some voltage level in between, the ESP8266 will use [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation), which is basically switching the voltage on and off quickly to mimic the intermediate voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Analog to Digital conversion is one aspect<sup>1</sup> where the ESP8266 is very poor. It has a single ADC pin which can read a maximum of 1V.

That pin is the only pin you can use with `analogRead()`. Any attempts to use any other pin just use that pin instead. The parameter (pin number) to `analogRead(pin)` is ignored and no matter what you do that one single ADC pin is what is being read. Also the pin cannot be used for anything else. None of the digital functions can be used with it since the pin doesn't have a GPIO number associated with it.

Some boards include a simple voltage divider on the ADC pin to allow higher voltages to be read, such as the NodeMCU:

[image]

If your board doesn't have such a divider you will have to implement it (or something similar) to be able to read the 3.3V incoming voltage.

---

<sup>1</sup> The ESP8266 is great for WiFi but pretty poor for everything else. It is seriously starved of internal peripherals (it doesn't even have I²C). For a more feature-rich solution you might consider upgrading to the ESP32.